# How to add ID proprety to asp.net MVC link element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, razor

I have the following link `<a href="@planUrl">@ResourceManager.GetResource("MemberLinkText")</a>` in my web application and I want to add an id to this link so that I can add a `$(document).onClick()` handler. However I can't seem to find a way to add an ID to this type of link. I have tried:

`<a href="@planUrl">@ResourceManager.GetResource("MemberLinkText") id="id"</a>` 
and 
 `<a href="@planUrl"> id="id" @ResourceManager.GetResource("MemberLinkText")</a>`

I am very new to this syntax and would be grateful for any help. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any attribute should be added inside the opening pair of `<>` (any where after tag symbol) of the element:

```
<a href="@planUrl" id="myLink">@ResourceManager.GetResource("MemberLinkText")</a>
```